# Joining a thread in a method that takes `&mut self` (like drop) results in "cannot move out of borrowed content"

Tags: multithreading, rust

I want to create a thread inside of the `new` method and stop it after the struct is destroyed:

```
use std::thread;

struct Foo {
    handle: thread::JoinHandle<()>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new(name: &str) -> Foo {
        let name = name.to_string();
        Foo {
            handle: thread::spawn(move || {
                println!("hi {}", name);
            }),
        }
    }
    pub fn stop(&mut self) {
        self.handle.join();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo::new("test");
    foo.stop();
}
```

This doesn't compile, and I can not understand why:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> <anon>:15:9
   |
15 |         self.handle.join();
   |         ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

And in newer versions of Rust:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.handle` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/main.rs:17:9
   |
17 |         self.handle.join();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.handle` has type `std::thread::JoinHandle<()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How can I fix this error?

In the future, I will implement `Drop` for `Foo`, and will call `stop()` from `drop()`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The function signature of [`JoinHandle::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) is:

```
fn join(self) -> Result<T>
```

This means that the method takes `self` (the receiver object) by values (taking the ownership/consuming it). But you only have a borrow to your `JoinHandle`; a mutable one, but still merely a borrow, **not** the ownership. Thus you can't call this method, because you can't move the ownership out of your borrow into this `join()` method.

An easy way to fix that, is by accepting `self` by value in the `stop()` method, too:

```
pub fn stop(self) {
    self.handle.join();
}
```

---

But you will notice that this isn't possible when implementing `Drop`, because `drop()` has the signature `fn drop(&mut self)`! Bummer! But there is a little trick you can use, described below. Please be aware that joining threads in `drop()` is probably not a good idea! Read [Matthieu M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791007/2408867) for more information on that!

If you still think, for whatever reason, that you really want to join a thread in `drop()`, you can store the `JoinHandle` in an `Option<T>` to save whether or not it's already joined. If you have a `Some(T)` you can obtain a `T` (by value!) from it by using the method [`Option::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take). Then you can write:

```
fn drop(&mut self) {
    // `self.handle` has the type `Option<JoinHandle<()>>` here!
    if let Some(handle) = self.handle.take() {
        handle.join().expect("failed to join thread");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer; this pattern of `Option` usage sometimes feels like one of Rust's best kept secrets.

Comment: Note: `join` returns a `Result`, it's bad to ignore results in general. At the very least, I recommend an `expect` in there to assert everything was OK. Or maybe printing the message carried by the error... at the same time, I'd recommend NOT to `join` in a destructor to start with. Having a potential infinite *wait* in a destructor is a bad idea, it breaks unwinding.

Comment: @MatthieuM. thanks for the hint. My answer now refers to yours and "handles" the `Result`.

Comment: The problem here is only cured symptomatically by using `Option` and `take()` which returns an owned instance. In case you have a reference to a `JoinHandle`, you will never be able to call `join` on it, no matter what you do and how: there is simply no way in Rust to make a reference become an self-owned object so that you may call methods with owned self like `JoinHandle::join()`. This is actually a problem I have and there is simply no way to even work around it. I simply don't want to have another Option for my join handle, as I already have one in the layer above, this is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 9):

**Don't**.

---

It may seem counter-intuitive, but joining a thread (or process) in a destructor is generally a *bad idea*.

Note that asking to join *does not* cause the thread to stop by itself; it's just about *waiting* for the thread to stop, and the thread may not. There are multiple reasons why this could happen:

- the handle being on the same thread as the one it controls,
- the thread to be stopped waiting on a channel the current thread should send a signal on,
- ...

Yes, that's a deadlock. An *implicit* deadlock.

A particular nasty situation is if your current thread panics (something unforeseen occurred). Unwinding starts... and blocks! And all the resources that this thread was supposed to clean-up hung in limbo, forever.

---

A better design is to instead create an explicit `join` method, which consume `self` (by value). It also lets you return a `Result`, in case joining causes an error.

And in order for your users to remember to join explicitly, `panic!` in the `Drop` implementation if they forgot to.

That is:

```
impl Foo {
    fn join(mut self) -> std::thread::Result<()> {
        match self.handle.take() {
            Some(h) => h.join(),
            None => Ok(()),
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if self.handle.is_some() {
            panic!("You MUST call either join on `Foo` to clean it up.");
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: I am aware that panicking in destructors is controversial, however it is much safer to abort a process when it's in an unknown state that go on and hope for the best.*

---

If you *really*, despite my warning, want to shoot yourself in the foot, join in `drop`.

Comment: doesnt this solution cause explicit panic at all times? drop will be invoked at the end of your 'join' method.

Additionally your code does not compile with an error:  
```error[E0509]: cannot move out of type `Foo`, which implements the `Drop` trait
 --> src/lib.rs:7:9  ```
Please consider rewriting this answer.

Comment: @AleksanderFular: Fixed. I always wanted destructuring to prevent `Drop` from running, but since it's not we can use an `Option` instead.

Comment: Wouldn't destructuring preventing Drop be a problem with something like `struct Fd { fd: libc::c_int }`? I think I'd want an explicit `.take(self)` method to extract the inner `fd` safely rather than destructuring silently passing "hey, you close this" semantics within the code.

Comment: @mathstuf: Destructuring is only available if you have access to the fields of the `struct`, which generally means that you are within the same module. In the same module, since you are establishing (and tearing down) the invariants of the object, it seems more useful than harmful. In general, though, you are right that this is a trade-off; a `take` is safer at the cost of having to create a "shadow" version of the type -- same list of fields, but within a tuple -- and maintain it over time.

Comment: This doesn't always help.
First of all, if you are using a framework which doesn't simply allow you to call your own owning method on your object - you have no other choice but to write it in the `drop`. At second, you can actually stop the thread in drop by sending the thread a message using mpsc::Sender and so cause it to stop there, so the point about the implicit deadlock is only partially valid. That means, there is no excuse for the `drop` method (or the `JoinHandle`) to disallow joining a thread. At third, you may simply want to create an RAII guard but this makes it impossible as well

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: There is no _generic_ method to stop a `thread`; you can send a message on a queue, yes, however you are still dependent on the logic in the thread actually reading _from that queue_. It's possible, but _brittle_. The thread logic could be blocked on anything else. A much more _lightweight_ implementation is to set an atomic, but once again the thread logic has to periodically check it -- if it doesn't for any reason, that thread is not stopping.

Comment: But this is absolutely has nothing specific with the drop, it can happen anywhere at any time. If a thread can't be joined, you simply can do exactly nothing about it, right? So I see no advantages over trying to stop a thread from a dedicated method rather than doing it in the `drop`. If you can't stop/join the thread in the `stop` method, you won't be able to do it anywhere else. It is like a poisoned mutex - if you have one, you can't recover it no matter how you try and where.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: It does; that's specifically what I'm addressing in my answer. Calling `join` is _explicit_, so the user can control where it happens -- and ensure it happens after having setting up everything -- whereas calling `drop` is implicit, it may happen as the result of an early return (`?` unwrapping) or unwinding (panic) before everything is fully setup.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in `join` signature:

```
fn join(self) -> Result<T>
```

so to fix your code, you need something like:

```
pub fn stop(self) {
    self.handle.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind unsafe code, then here's something you could do (please look at [Matthieus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791007/1021920) why this *can* be a bad idea).

```
struct Foo {
    handle: ManuallyDrop<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            let _ = ManuallyDrop::take(&mut self.handle).join();
        }
    }
}
```